# AvaloniaUI DoDragDrop() example?

Tags: avaloniaui

I want to do something like dragging from a text block on my application written with AvaloniaUI to Notepad to open the text file. The [documentation](http://avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Input/DragDrop/3404E3B1) seems lacking detailed information or example. I have tried the following code to pass "C:\Windows\win.ini" to Notepad, but did not work. How to make it work?

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);

        var DragTest  = this.Get<TextBlock>("DragTest");
        DragTest.PointerPressed += DragTest_PointerPressed;
    }

    private void DragTest_PointerPressed(object sender, Avalonia.Input.PointerPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MouseButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse down");
            var data = new DataObject();
            data.Set(DataFormats.FileNames, new string[] { @"C:\Windows\win.ini" });
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(e, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```